# What theory is used to describe photonuclear reaction and photodisintegration?

Tags: particle-physics

Assumption:  electroweak interaction

Background: I am interested in interactions of photons with matter. I just like to know at what point we can purely use the limiting case of QED and where we have to switch over to electroweak interaction. So is my table correct?

### interaction of photons with matter:

**QM/non-relativistic QED**
- Rayleigh-Scattering
- Photoeffect

**QED**
 - Compton-Scattering
 - pair production

**electroweak interaction ?**
 - photonuclear reaction
 - photodisintegration

Comment: You can describe all of these things in different ways. It all just depends on how precise you need that description to be. For practical purposes neither QED nor electroweak theory are of much use.

Comment: yeah, for practical purposes Bohr's model dies hard..